# Java SDK trying to access internet when it loads

Tags: java, development-environment

I generally only use Java for standalone app development. Today I upgraded my compilation engine to the 1.7u21 SE SDK and when it was loaded by my IDE my firewall was triggered by the "Java Platform Binary" trying to access the internet.

What component in the SE SDK is doing this? By "component" I mean the class file or native code that attempting this action.

Comment: Does your IDE use Java? The JRE is likely to try and look for updates

Comment: What IDE? What OS? As @MadProgrammer mentions, it may be your IDE; Intellij IDEA does that, for instance.

Comment: I am using Intellij IDEA. I assumed that because the firewall reported "Java Platform Binary" it was Java that was doing this. Is this an IntelliJ behavior that is using this name for its subprocess?

Comment: @TylerDurden IDEA is not a binary per se, it is a Java application... It uses the JRE to run.

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of possible explanations, most of them entirely harmless.  The application might be looking for updates, looking for XML schemas, or any number of other things.

The reason that this is reported as the "Java Platform Binary" is that any Java application that uses the standard `java` command under the hood will appear to the operating system as `java` ... not the application that you are running.  (And the same is true on Linux and UNIX.)

If this alert worries you just configure your firewall to refuse the attempted access.  But beware that this will apply to all Java programs ... not just the one you were running today.